# Using only C (no C++) for OpenGL?

Tags: c, opengl

I want to know if there is a possibility of using OpenGL in C without even scratching c++, tutorials or basic source codes are most welcome!

And if it is possible, how deep would my C skills have to be to understand and use it? I'm currently still mostly learning, and I like to do that by biting off more than I can chew.

Comment: Yes. You can use OpenGL with only C, but I can't think of any tutorials that cover that. There's a lot of nifty features in C++ that makes your life easer (not to mention the wide range of libraries that can compliment your program and reduce development time). Although I can think of cases where C++ just isn't an option. Is there something specific your aiming at? Perhaps we can give better suggestionz if we know what your end goal is.

Comment: As I said, I am still learning. And before I take off to C++, I want to be confident with my C skills, since I need them as an ongoing Engineer.
But what really motivates me, I have to say, is just my interest how the graphics work on a fundamental machine level, and the polar opposite, and that is how those beautiful graphics engines, like CryTec etc, are written.
I appreciate it, thanks!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

OpenGL is a C library, not a C++ one.

The only thing why almost all programs use C++ for OpenGL is there is a higher and simpler level manipulating it through some wrappers, libraries or frameworks. It's just more comfortable.

[Here](http://www.cs.rit.edu/usr/local/pub/wrc/graphics/redbook/openglbk/) are some good examples which were distributed along with the OpenGL "Redbook" (version 2.0).

**However, those examples use old-style OpenGL (rendering through functions), which is deprecated, you should always use shaders and buffers instead.** Although I think for beginning it can help.

[Here on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4559286/823738) was also discussed where to find **new** OpenGL examples.

Comment: those examples use "old" style OpenGL. I don't think you should encourage people to learn it. (Although I agree that it's a good example of what the author wanted - OpenGL with C)

Comment: @Xonar You're right I almost forgot about that. Thanks

Comment: @Zaffy: OpenGL is not really a library (despite its name), it's mostly an API specification. I backronymed it to Open Graphics Layer.

Comment: @datenwolf It is a library. But implementations may vary by specific vendors.

Comment: @Zaffy: Yes, that is another reason why I was confused. In the OpenGL wiki it explicitly stated that it is not a library and thus not #included and the language doesn't matter, while the specifications said it was a C based library.
So, this "redbook" is outdated. And OpenGL is still based in C, if I'm correct? So - are there any C examples for the new generation of OpenGL?
Much obliged, thank you!

Comment: @Zaffy: No, OpenGL **is not** a library. It's an API specification and there is no requirement in the specification whatsoever, that it's to be linked into a program as a library. It could very well be implemented in the form of messages that are sent using protocol buffers directly to the GPU. Or look at GLX/X11 transport. Just because you link a interface hook library into your program to use OpenGL doesn't mean that OpenGL, or any implementation of it, is tied to a library at all.

Comment: @BigBadWolf Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4559286/823738)